# GDAL "Permission Denied"

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I'm trying to convert a file using gdal-translate and keep getting a "Permission Denied" message.  Looking online (including here) the solution is usually to make sure you have write access to the directory.   Everything is being done locally, I'm a local admin, I created the directories and just to be safe went in and added myself into the folder security with "Full Control".  In trying to figure this out I've gone as far as logging in as the domain admin and still get the permission denied error.

Anybody have any ideas on what to try next?  User permissions should not be the cause here.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? One thing that comes into my mind is that on Windows user may not have rights for writing into Program files and GDAL perhaps wants to write some temporary files into installation directory.

Comment: I am on windows but as I stated I have the rights.  I am a local admin. Additionally I tried it as the domain administrator account and still got the error.  User rights should not be the problem here.

Comment: perhaps user rights shouldn't be the problem but that's what GDAL is telling you. If you're running this in a CMD window are you running it as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, running the command window as administrator

Comment: If you are on Windows 7 it may still be necessary to rise the rights for Program files and its sub-directories even for the admin account http://www.samlogic.net/articles/installation-program-windows-vista-7.htm. But if you know that it is not the case then it must be something else. Myself I tend to install GDAL to somewhere else than under Program files.

Comment: Can you show the exact command you're using (including the paths, with the exact quoting you're using). Please edit the question with those details.